# Get product details from the previous page

Tags: javascript, arrays, local-storage, google-tag-manager

I want take list of purchased products. Unfortunately there are no product details on my "order-received" page. Can I get product details from the previous page using GTM?

[Order-received Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n51Bm.jpg)

I have product details on a previous(basket) page:

```
function printOrderItems() {
      var hrefs = document.querySelectorAll("#form_cart > table > tbody > tr > td.product-info > a");
      var result = [];
      hrefs.forEach(function(t) {
          result.push(t.text)
      });
      return result;
}
```

[previous page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2VDI.png)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is it that you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

this is being created when a customer chooses to make an order correct? could you not, using a jquery click event, send that information via an ajax and then load your order received page dynamically from a handler?

Comment: No, I don't do that. I want to do this with google tag manager.

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need an answer: Use a custom HTML tag to extract the products on the basket page and store the result in [sessionStorage](https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage#Examples). SessionStorage accepts only a string, but you can use JSON.stringify to convert the array of product names into a string.

On the 'order-received' page use a variable of type Custom JavaScript to retrieve the products from sessionStorage. Use JSON.parse to convert the string back to an array. Then you can use this variable in any GTM tags that you want to run on that page.

Note though that sessionStorage is only available within the same subdomain and within the same tab. If that is an issue you could try to use a session cookie to persist the data from one page to the next. However, cookies are limited in size and therefore are not really suitable for persisting a potentially long list of product names.